# Magento 2. Retrieve information from env.php in the js files programmatically

Tags: magento2, configuration

I'd like to read and use the information stored in my env.php to my js files. Is there an entity that I can use to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Anil, this really bad idea to fetch the data directly from  `env.php` and It break the security of Magento.

I don't know why you need this but you have to build your logic another way without reading env.php and  So that M**agento security WILL NOT break**.

Also, ***php is the server-side language and where the js is client language***  if you want to read the data from php  then you have to store data at json varaible  to your browser.

Comment: HI @amit Bera, Actually we have some files which are apart from the Magento files as per our project requirement.
I'm trying to call site Url in both PHP and js files. So I cannot access the Object manager as these files are not Magento.